# Take a snapshot of a PKAddPassesViewController's view

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, passbook

I'm trying to take a snapshot of the view displayed when the user is prompted to add a pass.

The goal is being able to generate an image from a given pkpass

I was hoping something like this could work:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"columbus" ofType:@"pkpass"];
PKPass *pass = [[PKPass alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath] error:nil];

PKAddPassesViewController *pkAddPassesViewController = [[PKAddPassesViewController alloc] initWithPass:pass];
[self presentViewController:pkAddPassesViewController animated:YES completion:^(){
    UIImage *image = [pkAddPassesViewController.view captureView];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}];
```

With captureView being:

```
- (UIImage *)captureView
{
    CGRect screenRect = self.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor clearColor] set];
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);
    [self.layer renderInContext:ctx];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Guess what? I was wrong:

I tried:

- Using the completion callback and the animationFinished callback
- Setting the hidden property
- Using a timer to make sure the pass was visible on screen when the screenshot was taken
- Taking a snapshot of the parent view

I ran out of ideas, so any suggestion is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Oh, I've uploaded a minimal project here:
https://github.com/framp/demo-capturing-passbook

EDIT: 
I'm able to take a snapshot of other views and I can load other UIImage just fine with the code above.
The UIImage which is returned is a blank image

Comment: This is one of the things on my list to discuss with Apple next week.  There seems to be some anomaly with the PKPassViewController. If I find, or if they can show me a solution, I will post here.

Comment: I hope it's not intentional on their side (eg. to stop developers from generating images of passes)

Comment: That had crossed my mind too. I can think of a few cases where this could present a security risk, but at the end of the day I see no reason that would justify an intentional block.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might work for you.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(reportImage);
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work as well. I'm able to take snapshots of other views just fine, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The capture image code is good. Try with  : `[self.view.superview addSubview:imageView];` in the completion block instead of `[self.view addSubview:imageView];`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! Unfortunately the UIImage I receive from captureView is a blank image (and loading another UIImage works).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code if that work for you. Give the Coordinates which you want to capture and thats it. It will save your file in image album. It may give a warning but it works.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(320, 380));
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
 UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: Thanks but viewImage is still blank (which was to be expected, as the code is the same)

Comment: how do you know viewImage is blank ??

Comment: if you use the given code exactly then it should save the image in the album. Check if it is saving the image there and let me know please.

Comment: I tried it and it's not working on this particular PKAddPassesViewController's view. The problem is somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

I think `pkAddPassesViewController` is not fully loaded when you taken snapshot. So my suggestion is to take screenshot after some delay.
I hope it will work.

Comment: Tried that. I inserted a breakpoint before taking the snapshot and when I got to the breakpoint the pass was showing in all its glory

Comment: why not you try to write snapshot code in pkAddPassesViewController class in ViewWillAppear Method.

Comment: ViewDidAppear doesn't get called. I also noticed that if the app is waiting at a breakpoint, the pass view controller is still working and responding nicely

Comment: Now its time to work on code. will you please share you code with me, so that I can also work with you to fix this issue.

Comment: It's on github, I've mentioned the url at the end of my question!